# Restricting size of child control in a panel to visible area

Tags: wpf, infragistics, stackpanel, dockpanel

I can never seem to wrap my head around the differences between the DockPanel, StackPanel and Grid in terms of restricting their children content.  This XAML:

```
   <DockPanel>
        <Menu/>
        <ToolBarTray/>
        <ScrollViewer>
        <Grid>
          <Grid.RowDefinitions>
              <RowDefinition/>
              <RowDefinition/>
          </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TabControl>
         <TabItem Header="Data" Name="tabData">
                <DockPanel>
                    <Border Name="extraDataBorder" DockPanel.Dock="Top"
                            Style="{StaticResource ConsistentBorder}" Margin="10">                                    
                    </Border>
                    <igDP:XamDataGrid Grid.Row="1"                                                                      
                            Margin="10,10,10,0"                                                                             
                            ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                            ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"  >                       

                    </igDP:XamDataGrid>
                </DockPanel>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
         </Grid>                                                                                             

      </ScrollViewer>

    </DockPanel>
```

Produces a grid that is not constrained within the visible area of the screen as shown in the figure below:

[image: Overflowing grid]

I do not want the grid to extent beyond the visible area of the screen.  Instead, I want it clipped so that users can see the horizontal scroll bar and not have to scroll down to see the horizontal scroll bar.  I have tried using a Stack and DockPanel in place of the grid but get the exact same effect.  How do I fix this?

TIA.

**EDIT:**
I am editing the original XAML to include the additional elements that caused this issue.

Comment: What is the outermost DockPanel within? I ask because the from the screenshot it looks like the tab control is going below where you want the visuals to stop. That would seem to indicate that the outermost DockPanel or one of its ancestors is within something that is allowing it to be taller. Usually the problem is that one puts an element into a StackPanel (or a Grid whose RowDefinition has a Height of Auto) which basically means that the element is measured with an infinite height and therefore sizes based on how large the content wants to be.

Comment: Outermost DockPanel is within a UserControl.

Comment: Sorry but that still doesn't answer it as that UserControl must be hosted within something. Without a clear picture of the element hierarchy I can't really help you. In your image you have an arrow pointing to some element - what is the element tree relationship between the tab control and that element?

Comment: Andrew, you comment helped. I the XAML I initially posted was a modified version of the original.  I have since updated my original post.  However, I have since removed the ScrollViewer and Grid with rows set for auto-height and this has solved my problem.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

You can bind it to its parent's width and height as one of the many solutions.